# What's the content of the book that Aya read at the end of Mad Father?

Tags: mad-father

In the last scene of [*Mad Father*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/483980/Mad_Father/) game, Aya looks like reading a book that was lying on the ground, but she didn't explain to us what she read.

What is the book that [Aya](http://mad-father.wikia.com/wiki/Aya_Drevis) read at the end of the game?

Answer (score 1):

It's implied that the book she found was one of her father's. One end of the game has Aya opening a practice up with Maria afterwards.

She tells a patient that "She has lovely eyes", and given her father's tendency with body parts, I think she continued his experiments.

Because of this, I say the book is one containing her father's research.

Comment: why did aya interest with her father's research ? i thought she felt disgusted with her father's research after what she experienced in her house...Yes you are right said that aya continued her father's research so i am curious what exactly the content of her father's book that make aya interested with that kind of thing ? What kind of research ? i thought at the first game play, she read many book from her father's research (like anatomy, human part, baby's clone ) or diary from library, but she didnt even interest with it.  Until he read that book ath the end of the game...